# USB device not showing up in Titanium Studio

Tags: android, usb, titanium, appcelerator, adb

When I type "adb devices" I can see my usb device listed. USB debugging and unknown sources on connected device are enabled and yet still when I press run I don't see this device in Titanium Studio. I'm on Ubuntu 11.04. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I am also having this problem with Mac OSX.  There is not enough documentation on this...

Answer (score 1):

In Titanium Studio, when you deploy an application, you just see a generic 'Android Device', actually.